# How to pull addresses from word to use in Mail Merge?

Tags: microsoft-word, email, mail-merge

I am trying to figure out how to pull addresses from a Rich Text Doc. in Microsoft word to use the mail merge in Microsoft Access. This is being used for work and I need something as quick as possible, as I have a lot of other thing's to do.

The word document that the addresses need to be pulled from, also contain quite a bit of other information that I do not need included.

If there is another way to do this without using mail merge, or using a different program, I am open to suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can the info be out into excel? It's generally used as the mail merge source for access, word, etc. I believe it's because in excel the data is listed with headers. Word doesn't have this ability.